# Maximum of $f(t)=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{| e^{-ta}(1+at)+e^{ta}(1-at)|}{\sqrt{e^{-2ta}+e^{2ta}}}$

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, exponential-function

I want to find the maximum value of the following function
\begin{align}
f(t)=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{| e^{-ta}(1+at)+e^{ta}(1-at)|}{\sqrt{e^{-2ta}+e^{2ta}}}
\end{align}
for some $a>0$.

This function is symmetric around zero and has three local maximum ( from the graph) one of which is at zero. See the figure below.[image]

However, the lobs change their values, depending on what $a$ is, and the maximum doesn't alway happen at $x=0$.

I also try finding derivative at $f(t)$ but it is way to difficult to handle it, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20exp(-x%5E2%2F2)%20*%20abs%20(exp(-a*x)%20*(1%2Ba*x)%2Bexp(x*a)*(1-a*x)%20)%2Fsqrt(e%5E(2*a*x)%2Be%5E(-2*a*x))).

Answer (score 2):

I propose that $\eta = at$ to make things appear more clear. Secondly use:
$$\cosh{x}=\frac{1}{2}[\exp{(x)}+\exp{(-x})] \qquad \sinh{x}=\frac{1}{2}[\exp{(x)}-\exp{(-x})]$$ Then:
$$f(\eta) = \sqrt{2}\,\exp{\left(-\frac{\eta^2}{2a^2}\right)}\frac{\cosh{(\eta)}-\eta\,\sinh{(\eta)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(2\eta)}}}\tag{*}$$

I get rid of the absolute value because the all the extrema of $(*)$ are maxima of your original function. Since the function $f(\eta)$ is symmetrical wrt. the vertical axis you can look for only the extrema for $\eta\geq 0$, and what is more $f(\eta)$ cuts once the $\eta$ axis approximating to $0$ from negative values. Therefore the function will have for $\eta\geq 0$ two extrema: one maximum at $\eta=0$ (because $\cosh{(\eta)}-\eta\sinh{(\eta)}$ has a maximum for $\eta=0$) and one minimum which will move further from $0$ as $a$ does.

The extrema of $(*)$ cannot be found analytically (I guess), therefore I recommend you to use some numerical algorithm like Newton-Raphson to find the roots for a particular $a$.

$$\eta^{n+1}=\eta^n-\frac{f'(\eta^n)}{f''(\eta^n)}$$

It is easy, but tedious to calculate the derivatives of $(*)$. Since you are looking for one minimum only, you can begin with some arbitrary large enough seed for $\eta$. This value will tend always to the correct solution. Try for example $\eta=\sqrt{2}a$.